# when i try to make signed apk I cannot find it

Tags: android, apk

my app work well on my device when I run it but when I try to make signed apk to publish my app I can't find it .
 I tried a lot of times and searched in my project folder. 
How can I find my signed apk???

Answer (score 1):

In android studio
1) Click on 'Build' -> 'Generate Signed APK'
2) Fill keystore path ,alias, password...
3) Click on Next
4) You can see 'APK Destiantion Folder' field. Set your destination path as desktop
5) Click on Finish.
You can find your .apk file in desktop.

Comment: I know all that but I can't find the file . I tried to search all files with type *apk but no file

Comment: Click on 'locate'. 
it will redirect you to that location

or Please check folder name 'release' in your desktop

Comment: I clicked but nothing happed

Comment: please check that 'release' folder is created or not at your destination.
If it is created then you can find your apk file there with output.json file

Comment: There are no such files. But Android Studio writes: `APK(s) generated successfully`.

Answer (score 0):

### You need following things in order to produce signed apk file

- The keystore file which has the extension **.jks** and its password.
- The android project which has no compile-time errors.

The following steps to be followed.

1. Choose Build>Generate Signed apk option in the android studio.

[image]

2. Select the keystore file and enter its password.
3. Click Next then Finish.
4. After a successful build, you will get a link to the folder containing output file.

[image]

If you want to navigate manually, your signed apk file will be in

**Project Folder -> app -> release -> app-release.apk**

Comment: I know all steps and I did it but when I go to my Desktop there is no file .